# How to connect mysql with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to connect my database with nodejs but it's not connecting and giving an Error: connect ETIMEDOUT.

My code is...

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: hostname,
  user: user,
  password: pass,
  database: database_name,
});


con.connect(function (error) {
  if (error) console.log("Not Connected: " + error);
  else console.log("connected");
});
```

Comment: Change the value part to values that match your situation

Comment: Where is your database? WHat username do you want to use? What is the password of that Username? What database did you create, that will be that database name

Comment: I already tried with values and one of mine server is connecting with this code but this time my one server is not connecting...

Comment: With the same hostname, username and password are connecting to PHPMyAdmin

Comment: const mysql     = require('mysql');

Comment: Getting time because you database may b on remote side and not responding properly

Answer (score 0):

```
const mysql     = require('mysql');

const dbPool  = mysql.createPool({
                        connectionLimit : 10,
                        port            : 'port of your Db',
                        host            : 'host of your Db,
                        user            : 'user of your Db,
                        password        : 'password of your Db,
                        database        : 'database name,
                        dateStrings     : true,
                        debug           : false 
                    });
```